# Component won't re-render on state change, even though console.log in render function is called

Tags: reactjs, components, state, jsx, rerender

I'm sure I'm doing something silly here. I'm trying to write a component which, based on the fetching state of the data, renders one of 3 things.

1) An error message if the fetch has errored.
2) A loading message if the data is fetching.
3) The full child component if the data is fetched.

What's happening now is the fetch succeeds, but the Loading message won't disappear. In the code example below, you can see that I've added a console.log for whether or not the full render should occur. What's perplexing me is that this *will* eventually log as true, but the Loading message still shows.

This exact pattern seems to work for a sibling component in this app, so I'm confused as to what's missing here... Here's the entire component, it's been anonymized and stripped of styles, but the structure is otherwise identical.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        Data: state.NewDataReducer,
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchNewData: ActionCreators.fetchNewData,
};

const DataError = () => (
    <div>
        Error fetching new data!
    </div>
);

const DataLoading = () => (
    <div>
        Loading..
    </div>
);

class MainContainer extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        choice: PropTypes.string,
        fetchNewData: PropTypes.func,
        Data: ImmutablePropTypes.map.isRequired,
    }

    state = {
        choice: null,
    }

    componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        const { choice, fetchNewData, Data } = this.props;

        if(!choice) {
            return;
        }

        if(isFetching(Data)) {
            return;
        }

        const newChoiceSelected = choice !== nextProps.choice;
        if(newChoiceSelected) {
            fetchNewData({choice});
        }
    }

    handleChangeChoice = (choice) => {
        this.setState({
            choice: { choice }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { choice, Data } = this.props;

        const error = hasFetchError(Data);
        const loading = !error && !isFetched(Data);
        const renderFull = !loading && !error;

        console.log(renderFull);

        if(!renderFull) {
            return (
                <div>
                    Please wait.
                </div>
            );
        }

        const { dataBreakdown } = Data.get("dataKey").toJS();

        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent
                  choice={choice}
                  dataBreakdown={dataBreakdown}
                  onSetDrillDown={this.handleChangeChoice}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(MainContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your map function the arguments of what it needs to map over from immutable data types. Map creates a new a array and makes a callback function on the items that it iterates through in that array. This is just an example

`Data: ImmutabaleProptypes.map((ing, index)=>(
            <li key={index}>{Data}</li> // you can write jsx in here. 
        ));`

Comment: Thanks for responding! Do you mean in the container's props, or the child component's props? `dataBreakdown` in this case would be an array, and the child component does iterate over it. But by the point that the child component is being rendered, should my code have established that the relevant data was fetched? How could it be missing? Possible I'm missing something silly here.... thanks again

Comment: It not that its missing its that its not mapped when its being returned.

Comment: Ah - in this case `map` is the prop type I'm expecting back from the fetch, not a function.

Comment: try making a dataLoaded() that will render when then fetched data is returned.